# Dynamically generate add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette') colors based on CSS :root variables

Tags: php, css, wordpress, wordpress-gutenberg, gutenberg-blocks

Is there a way I can dynamically generate the color variables passed to the function below by reading them from the CSS :root variables?

I am currently only able to hard code them like the function below:

```
add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', array(
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Aqua', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'aqua',
            'color' => '#21a8af',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Purple Dark', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'purple-dark',
            'color' => '#632695',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Purple Light', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'purple-light',
            'color' => '#9e15bf',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Pink', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'pink',
            'color' => '#b5267b',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Black', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'black',
            'color' => '#1d1d2c',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'Grey Light', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'grey-light',
            'color' => '#f7f7f7',
        ),
        array(
            'name'  => __( 'White', CHILD_THEME_SLUG ),
            'slug'  => 'white',
            'color' => '#ffffff',
        ),
    ) );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is how I ended up doing it:

```
function color_exists($name, $colors) {
    foreach ($colors as $item) {
        if($item['name'] === $name) {
            return true;
        }
    }
    return false;
}
function update_color($name, $color, $colors) {
    foreach ($colors as &$item) {
        if($item['name'] === $name) {
            $item['color'] = $color;
        }
    }
    return $colors;
}
function render_color_classes() {
    $colors = create_colors_for_palette();
    if ($colors) {
        $css = ".components-panel__body.editor-panel-color-settings.block-editor-panel-color-settings.is-opened .block-editor-color-palette-control:first-of-type {display: none !important;}";
        foreach ($colors as $item) {
            $css = $css . ".has-" . strtolower(preg_replace('/(?<=\d)(?=[A-Za-z])|(?<=[A-Za-z])(?=\d)|(?<=[a-z])(?=[A-Z])/', "-", $item['name'])) . "-color { color: " . $item['color'] . " !important; }"; 
        }
        echo "<style>" . esc_html($css) . "</style>";
    }
}
function add_theme_color_options($file, $colors) {
    $lines = file_get_contents($file);
    $lines = explode(":root {", $lines);
    $lines = explode("}", $lines[1]);
    $lines = explode(";", $lines[0]);
    foreach ($lines as $data) {
        if (strpos($data, '--color') !== false) {
            $temp_color = explode("#", $data);
            $name = trim(str_replace(":", "", str_replace(" ", "", str_replace('--color', '', $temp_color[0]))));
            $slug = trim(str_replace(" ", "", str_replace('--color', '', $temp_color[0])));
            $color = "#" . trim(str_replace("", "", $temp_color[1]));

            if(color_exists($name, $colors)) {
                $colors = update_color($name, $color, $colors);
            } else {
                array_push($colors, array('name' => __( $name, $slug), 'slug' => $slug, 'color' => $color));
            }
        }
    }
    return $colors;
}
function add_brand_color_options($colors) {
    if (isset($_GET['post'])) {
        $post_id = sanitize_text_field($_GET['post']);
        $fields = get_fields($post_id);
        if (array_key_exists('vaccines_brand_color_light', $fields) && array_key_exists('vaccines_brand_color_dark', $fields)
        && $fields['vaccines_brand_color_light'] !== "" && $fields['vaccines_brand_color_dark'] !== "") {
            $name = "LightBrandColor";
            $slug = "light-brand-color";
            $color = $fields['vaccines_brand_color_light'];
            array_push($colors, array('name' => __( $name, $slug), 'slug' => $slug, 'color' => $color));
            $name = "DarkBrandColor";
            $slug = "dark-brand-color";
            $color = $fields['vaccines_brand_color_dark'];
            array_push($colors, array('name' => __( $name, $slug), 'slug' => $slug, 'color' => $color));
        }
    }
    return $colors;
}
function create_colors_for_palette() {
    $theme = wp_get_theme();
    if ($theme->Name != "vaccines") {
        return false;
    } else {
        if (isset($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT'])) {
            clearstatcache();
            $root_path = sanitize_text_field($_SERVER['DOCUMENT_ROOT']);
            $theme_folder_name = explode("/", get_stylesheet_directory_uri());
            $theme_folder_name = $theme_folder_name[6];
            $variablesFileMain = $root_path.'/wp-content/themes/vivid-main/css/style.css';
            $variablesFileTheme = $root_path.'/wp-content/themes/'.$theme_folder_name.'/css/style.css';
            if (!file_exists($variablesFileMain) && !file_exists($variablesFileTheme)) {
                return false;
            } else {
                $colors = array();
                if (file_exists($variablesFileMain)) {
                    $colors = add_theme_color_options($variablesFileMain, $colors);
                }
                if (file_exists($variablesFileTheme)) {
                    $colors = add_theme_color_options($variablesFileTheme, $colors);
                }
                $colors = add_brand_color_options($colors);
                return $colors;
            }
        }
    }
}
function handle_color_palette () {
    $colors = create_colors_for_palette();
    if ($colors === false) {
        add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette');
    } else {
        add_theme_support( 'editor-color-palette', $colors);
        add_action('admin_head', 'render_color_classes');
        add_action('wp_head', 'render_color_classes');
    }
}
handle_color_palette();
```

NOTE: This assumes you have a parent theme and are building off that with child themes. As a result, the main theme is queried first, and then the child theme will override any colors that are also declared in the main theme.